# Phonegap with custom url

Tags: cordova

I have an phonegap app that only use to load url.

config.xml:

```
    <content src="http://URL.COM" />
```

how can I now that apple will not reject my app?

thankts :)

Comment: It's a little unclear. How can you what?...

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't know what Apple will or won't reject until you submit the app in question.  That said you can do your best to follow the [Apple App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

Specifically, see section 2.12:

> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected